# Remove docker container without losing data in volume

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a persistent docker volume which will not get deleted when I remove my containers.

Steps: 
1. docker volume create mainvolume 
2. docker-compose up and it creates all three containers correctly 
3. I add some data to the database through the frontend and it creates adds it correctly 
4. docker-compose down 
5. docker-compose up 
6. The data persists in the db 
7. Likewise if i stop and restart any containers the data persists

However if I remove my containers and docker-compose up again then the data disappears.

I'm pretty sure this is a simple issue that I am not understanding being new to docker but none of the answers I can find on here or elsewhere seem to explain this scenario.

Code below

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
    frontend:
        build:
          context: ./TestClient
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports: 
        - '80:80'
        image: proj1:latest
        networks:
            - overlay
        depends_on:
            - backend
    backend:
        build:
            context: ./TestApi/TestApi
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: proj2:latest
        networks:
            - overlay
        ports: 
        - '5001:5001'
        depends_on:
        - db
    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "xxx"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
        ports:
            - "1433:1433"
        networks:
            - overlay
        volumes:
            - mainvolume:/var/lib/
networks:
  overlay:

volumes:
  mainvolume:
   external: true
```

Thank you in advanced for any help

Comment: [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-create-a-persistent-data-volume-for-postgres-database-container-within-a-docker-project) could probably help you. You have to take a look at how volumes work. In your case it would be like `- ./mainvolume:/var/lib/`, notice the dot at the beggining

Comment: If it indeed helped let me know so i can put is as an answer as well

Comment: Thank you, I will try it shortly and let you know